# Estimating forest cover density through Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, random-forest

I am trying to make a forest cover map (estimating forest canopy density) of a particular district and block. But I don't know where to start since I am a beginner. I have researched and came to a blog on [Google earth engine but they have given for a country](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/forest-cover-loss-estimation). Can we convert that to a district or block? Also I wanted to get the forest canopy density of year 2013 and 2023.

Here's the code that I am trying:

```
// Selected country (e.g. Bolivia).
var country = 'India';
// Canopy cover percentage (e.g. 10%).
var cc = ee.Number(10);
// Minimum forest area in pixels (e.g. 6 pixels, ~ 0.5 ha in this example).
var pixels = ee.Number(6);
// Minimum mapping area for tree loss (usually same as the minimum forest area).
var lossPixels = ee.Number(6);

// Load country features from Large Scale International Boundary (LSIB) dataset.
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB/2013');
var selected = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', ee.String(country)));
var gfc2018 = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2022_v1_10');
var canopyCover = gfc2018.select(['treecover2000']);
var canopyCover10 = canopyCover.gte(cc).selfMask();
// Use connectedPixelCount() to get contiguous area.
var contArea = canopyCover10.connectedPixelCount();
// Apply the minimum area requirement.
var minArea = contArea.gte(pixels).selfMask();
var prj = gfc2018.projection();
var scale = prj.nominalScale();
Map.addLayer(minArea.reproject(prj.atScale(scale)), {
    palette: ['#96ED89']
}, 'tree cover: >= min canopy cover & area (light green)');
var forestArea = minArea.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(10000);
var forestSize = forestArea.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: selected.geometry(),
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e13
});
print(
    'Year 2013 tree cover (ha) \nmeeting minimum canopy cover and \nforest area thresholds \n ',
    forestSize.get('treecover2000'));
    var pixelCount = minArea.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: selected.geometry(),
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e13
});
var onePixel = forestSize.getNumber('treecover2000')
    .divide(pixelCount.getNumber('treecover2000'));
var minAreaUsed = onePixel.multiply(pixels);
//print('Minimum forest area used (ha)\n ', minAreaUsed);
```